# How come this loop only echoes the first row in my table and not the rest?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I am using the Eloquent library and want to pull out every row of my table.

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$skole = null;

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    include 'connection.php';
    $skole = Skole::find($_GET['id']);

}

if($skole != null) {
$identifikasjon = $_GET['id'];
$skoleTilArrangement = Skole::where('id', $identifikasjon)->with('arrangementer')->get();

for($i = 0, $l = count($skoleTilArrangement); $i < $l; ++$i) {
    echo $skoleTilArrangement[$i]->arrangementer->type;
}

}
```

I have also tried this, which gives the same result (I can only pull out 1 out of 4 rows):

```
if($skole != null) {
    $identifikasjon = $_GET['id'];
    $skoleTilArrangement = Skole::where('id', $identifikasjon)-
>with('arrangementer')->get();


    echo $skoleTilArrangement->arrangementer->type;  
}
```

However, with this i can pull out the first row only:

```
echo $skoleTilArrangement[0]->arrangementer->type;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `var_dump` `$skoleTilArrangement` look like?

Comment: Try your for loop like this `for($i = 0; $i < count($skoleTilArrangement);++$i) {`

Comment: I tried your loop Jason, the exact same result.

Comment: well that's an issue then. I would have expected the result of the query to be in it

Comment: I tap out.  I don't know what your talking about. sorry. `var_dump($skoleTilArrangement)` I dont belive you that it dumps `$skoleTilArrangement = Skole::where('id', $identifikasjon)->with('arrangementer')->get();`

Comment: This is the var_dump of $skoleTilArrangement https://pastebin.com/vmWJdRR6

Comment: Just as a suggestion try replacing the final parameter of the for loop from `++$i` to `$i++`

Comment: I solved it like this:

$arrangementsListe = Arrangement::all();

if($skole != null) {
$identifikasjon = $_GET['id'];

foreach($arrangementsListe as $arrangement)
{
if ($arrangement['skoleId'] == $identifikasjon) {
echo $arrangement['overskrift'];
}
}

Comment: So you basically just getting all the records and doing the filtering in the php code? not recommended as when you start pulling thousands of records you will notice max memory allocation issues and time outs. but what ever works haha